# Dimensions position error in converting xarray.DataArray to xarray.Dataset

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a data array with structure `lat: 61`, `lon: 61`, and `time: 365`as:

```
xarray.DataArray lat: 61lon: 61time: 365
array([[[       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 1.06245708,
         1.04659652, 1.0071744 ],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        ...,
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan]],

       [[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
...
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan]],

       [[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        ...,
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan]]])
Coordinates: 

time (time) datetime64[ns]   1981-01-01 ... 2025-12-31T12:00:00
lon  (lon)  float64          67.5 68.0 68.5 ... 96.5 97.0 97.5
lat  (lat)  float64          7.5 8.0 8.5 9.0 ... 36.5 37.0 37.5
height ()   float64          2.0

Attributes: (0)
```

I converted this Data `xarray.DataArray` to `xarray.Dataset` as:

```
out_var_name = "tasmax"
dataset_out = final_array.to_dataset(name=out_var_name)
dataset_out
```

The output dataset (i.e. the **desired output**) should have the **structure of data variable** like : **(time, lon, lat)**

But obtained output has the structure of **data variable** like: **(lat, lon, time)**

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: (time: 365 lon: 61 lat: 61)
Coordinates:
time   (time)  datetime64[ns]   1981-01-01 ... 2025-12-31T12:00:00
lon    (lon)   float64          67.5 68.0 68.5 ... 96.5 97.0 97.5
lat    (lat)   float64          7.5 8.0 8.5 9.0 ... 36.5 37.0 37.5
height ()      float64          2.0

Data variables:
tasmax (lat, lon, time) float64 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan

Attributes: (0)
```

When I write this **xarray.Dataset** to **NetCDF**, then its dimensions somehow are

```
Dimensions  X: 365 Y: 61 Bands: 61
Origin  -0.5,97.75
Pixel Size  1,-0.5
```

i.e. Longitude took the position of time and Vice-Versa,

How to specify the right order of lat, lon & time ?

**Attempts:**

I tried to change the order of dimensions as:

1. Converted Array to Dataset

```
out_var_name = "tasmax"
dataset_out = final_array.to_dataset(name=out_var_name)
dataset_out
```

2. Cross Checked the position of Indices in dataset_out

```
current_indexes = dataset_out.indexes
current_indexes
```

which is:

```
lat: Float64Index([ 7.5,  8.0,  8.5,  9.0,  9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5,
                   13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0,
                   18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5,
                   24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26.0, 26.5, 27.0, 27.5, 28.0, 28.5, 29.0,
                   29.5, 30.0, 30.5, 31.0, 31.5, 32.0, 32.5, 33.0, 33.5, 34.0, 34.5,
                   35.0, 35.5, 36.0, 36.5, 37.0, 37.5],
                  dtype='float64', name='lat')
lon: Float64Index([67.5, 68.0, 68.5, 69.0, 69.5, 70.0, 70.5, 71.0, 71.5, 72.0, 72.5,
                   73.0, 73.5, 74.0, 74.5, 75.0, 75.5, 76.0, 76.5, 77.0, 77.5, 78.0,
                   78.5, 79.0, 79.5, 80.0, 80.5, 81.0, 81.5, 82.0, 82.5, 83.0, 83.5,
                   84.0, 84.5, 85.0, 85.5, 86.0, 86.5, 87.0, 87.5, 88.0, 88.5, 89.0,
                   89.5, 90.0, 90.5, 91.0, 91.5, 92.0, 92.5, 93.0, 93.5, 94.0, 94.5,
                   95.0, 95.5, 96.0, 96.5, 97.0, 97.5],
                  dtype='float64', name='lon')
time: DatetimeIndex(['1982-01-01 00:00:00', '1982-01-01 12:00:00',
                     '1982-01-02 00:00:00', '1982-01-02 12:00:00',
                     '1982-01-03 00:00:00', '1982-01-03 12:00:00',
                     '1982-01-04 00:00:00', '1982-01-04 12:00:00',
                     '1982-01-05 00:00:00', '1982-01-05 12:00:00',
                     ...
                     '2021-12-22 12:00:00', '2021-12-23 12:00:00',
                     '2021-12-24 12:00:00', '2021-12-25 12:00:00',
                     '2021-12-26 12:00:00', '2021-12-27 12:00:00',
                     '2021-12-28 12:00:00', '2021-12-29 12:00:00',
                     '2021-12-30 12:00:00', '2021-12-31 12:00:00'],
                    dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', length=365, freq=None)
```

3. Updated the order in which data structure is appearing in Data Variables

```
desired_order = ['lat', 'lon', 'time']
reordered_indexes = {index_name: current_indexes[index_name] for index_name in desired_order}
reordered_ds = dataset_out.reindex(reordered_indexes)
```

which gave the output as:

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: lat: 61 lon: 61 time: 365
Coordinates:
lat    (lat)  float64              7.5 8.0 8.5 9.0 ... 36.5 37.0 37.5
lon    (lon)  float64              67.5 68.0 68.5 ... 96.5 97.0 97.5
time   (time) datetime64[ns]       1982-01-01 ... 2021-12-31T12:00:00
height ()     float64              2.0

Data variables:
tasmax    (lat, lon, time)    float64   nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
Attributes: (0)
```

Here the **Dimensions** and **Data variables** had same order of lat, lon and time,

but still the output is same

[image]
[image]

The desired output is that number of bands should be **365** i.e. equivalent to time, however it somehow is taking latitude as band and time as the spatial coordinate.

How to do so?

Comment: I think you have two issues - 1 is how to reorder the dimensions of an array, which can be done with [`transpose`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.transpose.html), and 2- you must have a bug in your code which is resulting in writing something totally different. Maybe you have a variable name swapped? We could help you debug if you post your code as a [mre] but right now your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Hii @MichaelDelgado, it got rectified by transposing the dimensions as ```dataset_out.transpose('time', 'lat', 'lon')```. Thanks for guiding.